# Is there a way to resize a photo taken by the camera on iOs before upload with filepicker.io?

Tags: filepicker.io

During image upload on iOS we experience a memory spike at the end of the upload and we get memory warnings during upload of a picture taken by the camera (experienced on iPhone 5 and simulator). Additionaly, the upload takes pretty long. For our app we don't really need the full quality photo of the user.

Is there a way to resize the image before upload (like there is a setting for upload quality of a video)?

Comment: I would love this feature

Comment: +1 Would be a very useful feature

Answer (score 1):

Client side resizing is not currently supported. I'll add it to our tracker.

(It's worth noting that if you ask for an image/jpeg instead of an image/png, the size of the photo is significantly smaller)